# Postfix FROM header defaults

Tags: centos, email, postfix, smtp-headers

I have tried and tried to google my way out of this.  This definitely has to be a very common problem because I am half-way intermediate at Linux and etI am complaining about default settings and how to change them.

On the webserver I have a basic php-based contact form.  The user has the ability to put his/her name in the from field but Postfix will not take that value and actually use it.

For instance, if I put `John Doe` in for the from field, the emails headers appear like this

```
From John@vpsuser.vpslink.com
```

- This header does not contain the space nor Doe
- This header is appended with my server info.

How on earth do I fix this?  And if you don't want to tell me how for some reason, then at least point me in the right direction.  I have read several people's questions and answers and none of them seem to match up with my situation.

Some sources say to add such-and-such to the access file, or something else to transport.  whenever I view these files, they have the appearance of a man file and I am quite confused by it.

Somewhere in the whole postfix system, there is a default setting that takes away spacing and appends the user@hostname string.  Where/How can I fix that?

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with any postfix "default" settings. you need to check your php form.

Comment: I used this exact php form on another system and the emails came with the expected From header... so it is not a PHP issue IMO

Comment: Does it have anything at all to do with postfix?  I have looked all over for this problem to no avail.

Comment: A space in the from-address works at your place? Strange. And all users are internal and should mail from the domain vpsuser.vpslink.com?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the other host had their postfix (or whatever equivalent it is they used) to allow spaces and allow putting just a name in the From header.  That was a shared hosting account so I don't exactly know what they did.

I ended up changing my PHP afterall.  I put the name within double quotes and the email address within <> brackets and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your "problem" is described here:
[ADDRESS_REWRITING_README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html). This document describes some default rewrite-rules (including the logic for changing incomplete or malformed from-addresses).